# Windows 11 Search Panel Doesn't

Tags: windows-11

My Search Panel doesn't show any result (IT Appears But Doesn't show result After Input)  I don't know why but that happed after I removed this folder "AppData\Local\Packages" in order to fix nvidia control panel then I restarted my computer as requested in the solution that I was following while restart windows update upgraded my windows to the new version . any help cause I couldn't use my system without search

#windows version 22538. #preRelease 220114-1500

Comment: I am going to guess you remove everything within `AppData\Local\Packages`?  Since you are using a Insider Preview build the best bet would be to perform a Reset on your installation.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Appdata/Local/Packages- safe to remove?](https://superuser.com/questions/1237781/appdata-local-packages-safe-to-remove) Answer: Not safe at all.

Comment: Unfortunately, I always  remove windows.old  As I don't have enough space in c folder sol I couldn't reset my installation

Comment: @AhmedHalawa - Yes; You can indeed use the Reset.  Reset does not require Windows.old to exist.

Answer (score 0):

> I don't know why but that happed after I removed this folder
> "AppData\Local\Packages" in order to fix nvidia control panel

If you removed the whole Packages folder, you will have damaged many Windows Apps. You should not have done this.

I suggest the most effective repair now is to back up your data and reinstall Windows to fix the Packages issue.

If Production Windows 11 you can reinstall Production Windows 11.

If Windows 11 Insider, you need to reinstall Windows 10 and go back to Insider that way.

Comment: @AhmedHalawa - You permanently deleted the file. The only way to reset the file is to perform a Reset

Answer (score 0):

I Fixed It By Creating New Windows User with the same type (administrator)
then I logged out from my account and entered the new one

then I tested the search and it's works well

so I took a back up from the folder "AppData\Local\Packages" of the older account  then  I deleted it's content completely then I copied the content of the new account folder "AppData\Local\Packages" into the old

after that I logged into the old account and it's works now well

Thanks every body .

Comment: That was lucky indeed. There may be some apps however that do not work as expected and you will only find out as you use and test apps.